# MVC3 ActionLink giving a strange result for me

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I hvae a problem with ActionLink. Here's my code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "disabled" })
```

And the result:

```
<a class="disabled" href="/?Length=4">Home</a>
```

Can someone tell me why it's give me "?Length=4". Am I doing something wrong when I request it to use the class of disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong method signature...

Try using:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "disabled" })
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your htmlAttributes object are passed in as the route data. Change your code to this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "disabled" })
```